# Plagrism chacker script with curl having issue

Tags: php, curl

I create a function in php. It is working currectly on localhost xamp.

```
function counter($search,$withKts = '0') {
        $search = urlencode($search);
        if($withKts) $search='"'.$search.'"'; 
        $ch = curl_init();
        $url = "http://www.google.co.in/search?q=".$search."&btnG=Search&meta=";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $result=curl_exec ($ch);
        $error = curl_error($ch);
        $errorno = curl_errno($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);   

        $regex = '~resultStats">\s*(.*?)\s*result~';
        preg_match($regex , $result, $match);
        $counts =  $match[1];
        $counts = str_replace("About ","", $counts);

        if($counts > 1500)
            return 0;
        else
            return $counts;
    }
```

Here are screenshots of offline checking and online checking of same string.

And i already check the curl is enable by echo 'Curl: ', function_exists('curl_version') ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled';

Can anyone please point what the error is?

[image: Search result on lcalhost]

[image: Search result on server]

Comment: Have you checked your error log?